# Is there an actively maintained Truecrypt repository

Tags: ppa, repository, truecrypt

The last time I installed [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (on Debian) I built the package myself. I'm now on Ubuntu 11.04 and I'd rather not do that again. The only [download](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads) they have on their site is a tarball, but I prefer to install from a package than manually where possible.

Is there an actively maintained PPA or repository somewhere with Truecrypt for Ubuntu 11.04, or even just built packages available to download?

(I realise it's kept out of Ubuntu and Launchpad because of licensing issues, but that doesn't mean there isn't another repo elsewhere...)

Comment: ***WARNING: TrueCrypt is no longer maintained and likely insecure.***  You may wish to be looking at VeraCrypt or other software as an alternative to TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the PPA I created for this. It contains a patch I created that adds an appindicator to it, since the old systray is no longer supported in Ubuntu. https://launchpad.net/~stefansundin/+archive/truecrypt

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stefansundin/truecrypt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

The version is 7.1a, and I do not intend to update to 7.2 because it has less functionality.

Answer (score 3):

[v7.1 of true-crypt](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/312674) exists in the SuperOS PPA for Oneiric & Lucid (v7.0a for Natty)

Suggestion would be to install this external PPA - install truecrypt and immediately via Software Sources, disable (untick) the SuperOS source.  The reason for this, SuperOS contains many packages that  you may not want to upgrade to. The choice is yours.

**to install**

Installation instructions are on the [SuperOS website](http://hacktolive.org/wiki/Super_OS_repository)

The [SuperOS deb](http://hacktolive.org/download/super-os-repo-installer.deb) you download installs the PPA and the GPG keys

Once you have added the PPA

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

**as with all PPAs - this can make your system unstable - have a valid disk-image that you can restore to**

<sub>not tested by myself</sub>