# How do I install TrueCrypt?

Tags: truecrypt

I have a Windows 7 machine with TrueCrypt. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with the intention of converting to an Ubuntu only machine but I can't install TrueCrypt on Ubuntu.

I have been looking through the forums and have followed all advice to the letter and still TrueCrypt doesn't work; I have only a non-functional icon in "dash". Should I uninstall Ubuntu and start over (ie reinstall)?

### Note by community:

TrueCrypt is no longer developed or supported, and is no longer considered secure, [according to TrueCrypt's website](https://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: How did you install?  What have you tried?

Comment: No need to Re-Install entire Ubuntu OS for Truecrypt , please provide info as in above asked by  Mitch.

Comment: I downloaded Truecrypt for linux, 32 bit. Following various methods, I checked "open with archive manager" or "save file", then on Ubuntu 12.04 I tried "run in terminal" or "run". I am not new to Truecrypt and in all cases I followed all instructions. Nothing worked even though the advice was for other people and it worked for them. I shoul add that I uninstalled Truecrypt in windows and with each failed install in Ubuntu I uninstalled the download and started over with someone else's method (as described above). Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13):

If you prefer to install from a ppa you can use this one for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-astrapi/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

And to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:michael-astrapi/ppa
```

In the past others have used different PPA: [link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65673/is-there-an-actively-maintained-truecrypt-repository)

Comment: No longer working for me :(

Comment: I got this error on Ubuntu 23.10: "ERROR: ppa 'michael-astrapi/ppa' not found (use --login if private)"

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issues on ubuntu 12.04 & installing truecrypt 7.1

however finally what worked was simply:

```
tar xzvf truecrypt*.gz
```

- this extracted the file truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86 in the same directory.

Then I ran the command:

```
./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86
```

This will install  everything perfectly.

sunil

Comment: Thank you. I had run into problems with the other solutions (using a repository and apt-get), but this is the one solution that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'll break it down, although I'm verbose, this is the simplest way.

Go to http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads

Scroll down to Linux and select the `Standard` version that matches your bit depth (32-bit or 64-bit) and download it.

After the download completes, Double click on the downloaded file and it should automatically open with the Archive Manager.

At the top of the Archive Manager, click `Extract` and select a destination folder, I picked `Downloads`

Press the `Start` button on your keyboard (The button between the left Ctrl & Alt) and type the word `Terminal` and press the enter key.

Here you will type commands inside terminal:
You'll need to Change Directory (CD) to where you extracted the truecrypt setup file, if you followed my example, it would be this (note your path is case sensitive):

```
cd Downloads
```

To start the install, highlight and copy one of these commands and paste it into the Terminal window. (to paste, right click and select paste).

For 64 bit:

```
./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64
```

For 32 bit:

```
./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86
```

You then shuold get a xmessage window with an option at the bottom to `Install TrueCrypt`, click it.

The next window will be an xmesssage License message, click `I accept and agree to be bound by the license terms`

The next window will tell you how to uninstall it, if you don't plan on uninstalling it, you can skip this information.

The last window will be titled `TrueCrypt Setup` and have the information where it installed and will finish with `Press Enter to exit...` I recommend you press enter.

You're done.

Press the `Start` button again and type `TrueCrypt`, (capitalization unimportant) and press enter to open

Tip: If you want it on your unit bar, simply use your mouse to drag the TrueCrypt icon to your unity bar.

Note: if you have an unconventional keyboard layout with no 'Start' you could open Terminal from the 'Dash Home' in the side-bar.

Answer (score 3):

Another PPA is available [here](https://launchpad.net/~stefansundin/+archive/truecrypt).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stefansundin/truecrypt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

This version also includes an application indicator menu in the Ubuntu title bar.

At the time of this answer's last edit, the version available is 7.1a.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of TrueCrypt works perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04 and all later versions of Ubuntu provided that you install all of its required dependencies. In Ubuntu 12.04 and later, open the terminal and type.

```
sudo apt-get install bzr libncurses5-dev gcc debhelper devscripts dpatch
```

Then install TrueCrypt the usual way with `tar xzvf truecrypt*.gz` followed by either `./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64` (for 64-bit OS) or `./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86` (for 32-bit OS).

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

To install Truecrypt from http://namhuy.net/889/how-to-install-truecrypt-on-ubuntu.html

```
$ wget http://www.truecrypt.org/download/truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x86.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf truecrypt*.tar.gz
$ ./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86
```

Create truecrypt key:

```
$ truecrypt --create-keyfile /etc/tc.key \
--hash=Whirlpool \
--random-source=/dev/urandom
```

Change permissions for truecrypt key

```
$ chown 600 /etc/tc.key
```

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

TrueCrypt development ended 5/2014.

VeraCrypt is a forked replacement for TrueCrypt and can be found at  [CodePlex](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/). There is also a PPA available which can be found [there](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Contributed%20Resources) as well.