# How install Truecrypt on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit

Tags: truecrypt

1.I have downloaded the linux version from http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads
2. Right click on the file (truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x86.tar.gz), ->Open with Archive Manager.
3. Double click on the extracted file (truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86), nothing happens.

Someone can help me installing truecrypt on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit?

SOLUTION!! The extracted file works if in the terminal is typed: ./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Truecrypt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174872/how-do-i-install-truecrypt)

Answer (score 17):

Since the truecrypt website no longer contains version 7.1a, I'm posting this.

I recommend the truecrypt PPA I created. It contains a patch I created that adds an appindicator to it, since the old systray is no longer supported in Ubuntu. https://launchpad.net/~stefansundin/+archive/truecrypt

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stefansundin/truecrypt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

The version is 7.1a, and I do not intend to update to 7.2 because it has less functionality.

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you also need to install dmsetup `sudo apt-get install dmsetup`

Comment: Since the last update dmsetup is a dependency and should be installed automatically. Thanks Tim.

Comment: Who is that @stefansundin guys and why should we trust him? Just saying...

Comment: @ZAB If you are in a situation where you need absolute security, then I absolutely recommend that you compile TrueCrypt yourself. I am trying to make it easy for anyone, beginner or not, to use TrueCrypt. The good thing about launchpad, is that you can verify that there is no malicious code since the binaries are compiled by launchpad and all the inputs to the compilation is available for download. It is always good to be extra cautious if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

you can also right-click the file and click on execute to do the same job from GUI

or from terminal "cd" your way to the file location and use "./" then file name to execute it.

```
./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86
```