# Opening True Crypt volumes and files. 14.x

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt

I have two drives in my computer. One boots Win7 the other Ubuntu 14. I have external USB drives with banking and other data that are encrypted with truecrypt.  I don't want to use BitLocker and have to redo my encryption because Windows 10 (if I upgrade) has bitlocker and they admit to saving your passords in their cloud (in case you forget!)

GRC's audit has stated TrueCrypt is still safe and a security audit shows this to be the case.  I have no desire to change encryptions and it looks like another group my resurrect true crypt again.

I have tried all manner of methods to install TrueCrypt on Ubuntu and the most I have accomplished is an icon in my navigation that does nothing.

Even if I need to use another program to open existing truecrypt files and drives without altering them I can live with that. But I prefer to get a version of truecrypt actually working, even a stand-alone version.

Can someone point me in the right way to be able to access my drives and files without altering them so I can also access then from Windows as well?

( Side question, can I use a windows version via WINE to accomplish this? )

Comment: Can you open a terminal and see what happens if you try to execute `truecrypt`? Did you see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453951/how-install-truecrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-32-bit) answer?

Answer (score 0):

`cryptsetup` from the `cryptsetup-bin` package that's normally installed by default, should be able to open TrueCrypt or tcplay encrypted partitions. See `man cryptsetup` for info like:

```
   open --type tcrypt <device> <name>
   tcryptOpen <device> <name>  (old syntax)

          Opens the TCRYPT (a TrueCrypt-compatible) <device> and sets up a
          mapping <name>.

          <options> can be [--key-file, --tcrypt-hidden,  --tcrypt-system,
          --readonly, --test-passphrase].

          The  keyfile  parameter  allows combination of file content with
          the passphrase and can be repeated. Note that using keyfiles  is
          compatible with TCRYPT and is different from LUKS keyfile logic.
```

I'd also use the `--verbose, -v` option to get more info the first time it's run, and see `dmesg` / `/var/log/syslog` if there are any errors. And once opening the device you'd still have to mount it.

Disks / `gnome-disks` might provide a graphical way to open & mount partitions, and unmount/`umount` & close them (even if it doesn't work to open them).