# Configure Truecrypt to work seamlessly

Tags: permissions, truecrypt

OK, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174872/how-do-i-install-truecrypt) shows how to *install* Truecrypt on Linux. But how to *configure* it correctly in Ubuntu 14.04, so it works fine:

- a normal user should be able to mount a truecrypt volume without the need to enter an administrator's password, his own password should be sufficient
- make the by default created icon (`/usr/share/applications/truecrypt`) work (by default the GUI launches, but one gets "Permission denied" errors even when just exiting; prepending "pkexec" the command in the Exec line does not help)

Currently, I have to execute `sudo truecrypt` in a terminal. After mounting this opens the volume in a new "Files" window (though the according truecrypt option is unselected) which I always have to close. If you make the error to click the Exit button, truecrypt keeps running but without any window. Then you have to open another terminal and run `sudo truecrypt` again.